# Unable to write to files with mod_python and PSP

Tags: python, apache, permissions, mod-python, python-server-pages

So, I have a Python Server Pages script that when ran, saves stuff to a file in `/var/www/`. It opens the file with:

```
open(filename, 'wb')
```

Which causes this:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.txt'
```

I'm using Apache and have set `/var/www/` to `chmod 755`. I'm not sure if www-data is trying to write, since when I run this, the output is simply `0`:

```
<%
import os
req.write(str(os.system('whoami')))
%>
```

I `chown`'d it to `www-data` anyway, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Why do you use mod_python? It's obsolete since a long time in favour of mod_wsgi. Mixing code and HTML (PSP/PHP-style) is also a pretty bad idea. Consider switching to a small-footprint WSGI framework such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't do enough searching, managed to solve it by writing using the full path, ie.

```
open('/var/www/' + filename, 'wb')
```

instead of

```
open(filename, 'wb')
```

Comment: You probably had a working directory like `/`, i.e. one that was not writable to you.